"Attempted to read or write protected memory" when training model using microsoft.ML.LightGbm library
I have problem with my code, where I am trying to train model but the System.AccessViolationException is shown. I do not understand why, because I have the same code in my other project, the one difference is that the project where the exception is shown, is Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) and the project where there is no exception shown, is console application. I am using microsoft.ML.LightGbm library.
 private void RunLightGBMAlgorithm()
 {
     var mlContext = new MLContext();

     var dataView = LoadData(mlContext, FilePath);

     int iterations = 100;
     double totalMicroAccuracy = 0;

     for (int iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++)
     {
         var shuffledData = mlContext.Data.ShuffleRows(dataView);

         var splitData = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(shuffledData, testFraction: 0.2);

         var trainData = splitData.TrainSet;

         var testData = splitData.TestSet;

         var trainer = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.LightGbm(labelColumnName: "Label", featureColumnName: "Features");

         var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label")
             .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", new[] { "Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "Z4", "Z5", "Z6", "Z7", "Z8" }))
             .Append(trainer);

         var model = pipeline.Fit(trainData);
         var predictions = model.Transform(testData);
         var metrics = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Evaluate(predictions);

         totalMicroAccuracy += metrics.MicroAccuracy;
     }

     double overallMicroAccuracy = totalMicroAccuracy / iterations;
 }


Picture of the exception:

I try to update .net to 6.0 in the project with exception, because the other project had target framework .net 6.0 too, but I still have the same problem.
